# How to capture current time on value list field change as in set date to current date

Tags: archer

How to capture current time for value list field change as in set date to current date.Need to capture curtent time  with current date when value list field change value. Incident close time with current date.

Comment: Feel free to up-vote and mark correct answer if any of the answers have helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it seems obvious that the field 'Incident Close Time' is a calculated one.

The calculation would be:

```
IF(
    AND(
        [Incident Status] = VALUEOF([Incident Status],"Closed"),
        ISEMPTY([Incident Close Date])
    ),
    NOW(),
    [Incident Close Date]
)
```

Two things to take care here:

Firstly, if the Incident Status is a calculated field, make sure the status field is above the time field in the calculation order.

Secondly, if you want to capture the time as well, make sure the field 'Incident Close Date' field is set to capture 'Date and Time' in the options tab of the field configuration. You can do this by checking off the calculation, selecting the 'Date and Time' option and checking on the calculation again.